# Dropzone.js only uploads 2 files at once on each request

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I'm using DZ for uploading both soundfiles and images in my .NET MVC web app. I need to achieve that on one single request all selected files are uploaded at once. To my understanding to achieve this one should use the DZ properties uploadMultiple and parallelUploads. However having both properties set to true does not work.

My Html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadSound", "ManageFiles", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "dropzone", id = "dropzoneSound", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="soundId" id="sId" value="0" />
    <div class="fallback" multiple="multiple">
        <input type="hidden" name="file" value="" />
    </div>
}
```

My endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadSound(int soundId)
{
    var storedFilenames = new List<string>();

    if (soundId > 0)
    {
        checkFolderExist(Server.MapPath("~/sounds/" + soundId), new List<string>());

        for(int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++){
            storedFilenames.Add(SaveFile(Server.MapPath("~/sounds/" + soundId), Request.Files[i]));
        }

        return Json(new { message = storedFilenames });
    }
}
```

Below code triggers the endpoint but only 2 files gets uploaded at the same time. The endpoint gets invoked until all files have been uploaded.

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneSound = {
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        maxFilesize: 16, //MB
        maxFiles: 6,
        parallelUploads:6,

        removedfile: function (file) {
            var self = this;
            var s = document.getElementById('soundFile');
            var param = {
                "filename": s.value,
                "soundId": 0
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSoundFile", "ManageFiles")',
                data: JSON.stringify(param),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var soundFileHTML = document.getElementById('soundFile');

                    var _ref;

                    return ((_ref = file.previewElement) != null && _ref.parentNode != null) ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : null;
                }
            });
        },

        init: function () {
            this.on("addedfile", function () {
                if (this.files[9] != null) {
                    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
                }
            });

            //DZ only uploads 2 files at a time. when 2 files have been uploaded autoProcessQueue has to be set again to trigger next files to upload, if any
            this.on("processing", function (data) {
                this.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
            });

            this.on("complete", function (data) {

                if (data.xhr != undefined) {
                    var res = JSON.parse(data.xhr.responseText);

                    var sIds = document.getElementsByClassName('sId');

                    for (i = 0; i < sIds.length; i++) {
                        sIds[i].value = res.soundId;
                    }
                }
            });
        },
    };
```

When modifying the DZ with the code below the request does not reach to the endpoint:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneSound = {
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        maxFilesize: 16, //MB
        maxFiles: 6,
        parallelUploads:6,
```

Anyone having the same problem, or having a solution to the problem? 
All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this error and observed that only two of the files I drag into the dropzone are actually included in the multi-part form post. My issue was that I was omitting parallelUploads from my configuration object. I'm not sure why this works for me and didn't work for OP. One difference between OP's implementation and mine is that I'm using Dropzone with [imperatively rather than declaratively](https://docs.dropzone.dev/getting-started/setup/imperative).